# Android Eclipse application, compatible error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing Android app just for hobby, and I made an app, when I test on my phones works well, I tested on :

- Alcatel idol OneTouch 2S ( 6050y )
- Sony Xperia Tipo ( st21i )
- Samsung Galaxy Ace
- Asus Memo Pad HD7 (Tablet)

Works great, and no error at all...
but when I tested on Samsung Galaxy S4, and Samsung Galaxy S3..
no background music (on Galaxy S4 and no background pics are shown ), and what I click I see report error message so application crushes..

Error Log:

```
03-20 16:55:07.366: D/skia(29417): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
03-20 16:55:07.376: D/AndroidRuntime(29417): Shutting down VM
03-20 16:55:07.376: W/dalvikvm(29417): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4206c700)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.**********a/com.***********a.Info}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at *********.Info.onCreate(Info.java:16)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    ... 11 more
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    ... 23 more
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:475)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
03-20 16:55:07.391: E/AndroidRuntime(29417):    ... 26 more
```

Please any help ?

Comment: post those error messages,

Comment: I think is from big image on backround.jpg...
I changed it and now It is working on S3... but still not tested on S4 and some other phones...
Or maybe that was the problem...

Comment: yea you are right on the money. thats the out of memory exception - allocation failed for scaled bitmap.. . so probably scale image, and everthing will be done. probably go with 400 * 400 okay, i think is average

Comment: Problem solved, now it is working well :) Thnx